# LINQ query to filter items inside a list of list

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a a list of items which contains `ICollection` of more items and I was wondering if someone could help me with a lambda expression to filter this list.

Here's what my list looks like:

```
Public Class ItemDto
    Public Property ItemId As Integer
    Public Property ItemLs As ICollection(Of ItemLDto) = New HashSet(Of ItemLDto)
End Class
```

This is a quick look at what the objects would look like

```
ItemID = 1
     ItemLs (Id=1, Type=2)
     ItemLs (Id=2, Type=3)
ItemID = 2
    ItemLs (Id=1, Type=2)
    ItemLs (Id=2, Type=3)
ItemID = 3
    ItemLs (Id=1, Type=2)
    ItemLs (Id=2, Type=3)`
```

What i want to do is create a LINQ query that will return the following results. Basically filtering out all the `ItemLs` with a `Type=3`. I'm not sure why this eludes me as it seems like it should be so simply

```
ItemID = 1  
    ItemLs (Id=2, Type=3)
ItemID = 2
    ItemLs (Id=2, Type=3)
ItemID = 3
    ItemLs (Id=2, Type=3)
```

Trying to avoid putting it into a loop and creating a new object but currently i loop through it with this query which isn't ideal.

```
item.ItemsLs.FirstOrDefault(Function(m) m.Type = 3)
```

Thanks for any pointer

Answer (score 3):

`SelectMany` is what you're looking for I think, which is much easier to reason about using syntax based query:

```
Dim result = From parent In source
             From child In parent.ItemsLs
             Where child.Type = 3
             Select New With { .ItemDto = parent, .ItemLs = child  }
```

It will also work in case where there are multiple `child` items with `Type = 3`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but that you for helping me get further. The results i get are now are as follows. I'll continue to alter it to see if i can get the results.
ItemID = 1
     ItemLs (Id=1, Type=2)
     ItemLs (Id=2, Type=3)
ItemsLs
     (correct info for itemID =1)                                                                       
ItemID = 2
    ItemLs (Id=1, Type=2)
    ItemLs (Id=2, Type=3)
ItemsLs(correct info for itemID =2)